# View completely covering another view

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a view that is completely covering another view to "gray it out". So I added a view that has a somewhat transparent color on top of it with a RelativeLayout. However, even though I'm using "fill_parent", the view on top occupies 0 height. If I change to, for example, a TextView, it occupies as much space as wrap_content would. How can I make my view on top cover the entire View beneath it (which may vary in size)?
My real code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/unit_entry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="3dip">

    <include layout="@layout/view_stats"
        android:id="@+id/unit_stats"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/unit_stats">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/view_heading_value_text"
                android:id="@+id/unit_exp_layout"/>

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/unit_skills_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:hint="@string/skills_injuries_hint"
                android:background="@drawable/border"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/unit_equipment_text"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:hint="@string/equipment_hint"
            android:background="@drawable/border"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View android:id="@+id/unit_overlay"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray_overlay"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Example to illustrate what I want:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/unit_entry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="3dip">


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1"
        android:text="text2"/>

    <View android:id="@+id/unit_overlay"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#88666666"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In this example I would want unit_overlay to cover both text1 and text2.

Comment: Could you post your included layouts too? Because I can'try this code without them..

Comment: why there is a `android:orientation="vertical"` in your view?

Comment: @FarukYazıcı Added a more easily testable example.

Comment: @TheRedFox Played around with different views, a LinearLayout among others and forgot to remove that line. Edited.

Comment: I've answered it based on your testable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer to your question over the second example;

1. Put the `TextView`s in a layout with an ID
2. Adjust your `View`'s align parameters as follows;

   ```
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/texts"
   android:layout_alignRight="@+id/texts"
   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/texts"
   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/texts"
   ```

By doing this, you are forcing that view to stay in bounds of the other layout.
So the complete code for your testable example will be;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/unit_entry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="3dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/texts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text1"
            android:text="text2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/unit_overlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/texts"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/texts"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/texts"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/texts"
        android:background="#88666666" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just try this and you will see it covers only the texts :)

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure which of the views in your code is the one that should be covered, but generally what you want is done like this:

First, put the view you want to cover in a separate RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:layout_height = "@+id/covering_view"
        android:background = "@color/ /*the grey-out color here */"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"  />

    /* Your view which you want to cover */

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then put this into the place where your view is right now :-) When you want to grey-out or ungrey-out the view, simply change the `visibility` of the `covering_view` View :-)

As for your example, please try changing the overlay view as follows:

```
<View android:id="@+id/unit_overlay"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray_overlay"
    />
```

Comment: The RelativeLayout is an entry in a list. I want to the covering view to cover the entry (i.e. the entire RelativeLayout named unit_entry)

Comment: match_parent and fill_parent both make the view occupy 0 height.

Comment: Try setting the height/width of the top RelativeLayout to match_parent as well

Comment: That makes no difference.